# could not broadcast input array from shape (2352) into shape (784)?

Tags: python

well, I used "resize" to shape the size of img, but the error  is "could not broadcast input array from shape (2352) into shape (784)"

```
    img = Image.open(filename)       
    img=img.resize((28,28))        
    img_ndarray=numpy.asarray(img,dtype='float64')/32        
    number[j]=numpy.ndarray.flatten(img_ndarray)
```

so I tried to test it and write the next:

```
    img = Image.open(filename)        
    img=img.resize((28,28))        
    img_ndarray=numpy.asarray(img,dtype='float64')/32
    print 1
    a=[];
    a=numpy.ndarray.flatten(img_ndarray)
    print len(a)
```

and I found `a=2352=784*3`!
why? 
img.resize is useless?

Comment: It doesn't work because `28 * 28 != 2352`

Comment: You can resize your array like this `img = img.resize((3, 784))` because `3 * 784 = 2352`. Or like this `img = img.resize((3, 28, 28))` because `3 * 28 * 28 = 2352`.

Comment: but I want size 784, and now I get confused about the "resize"..where is "3" come from..??

Comment: So the best way is to interpolate your data like this : `img = numpy.interp(np.arange(782), np.arange(2352), img)`

Comment: could you explain "resize" to me? I think resize(28*28) means we use a 28*28 matrix to store a picture.

Comment: `resize` means that you change the shape of your array. If the new shape total number of elements is different from the old shape total number of elements, `resize` can't work.

Comment: Can I post my comment as an answer ?